# add layout to view in separate class

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working with the cards UI library.  I have a class("MyCard") that has its own view inflated.  I'm calling that class from my main activity.  What I want to do, is add a relative layout to the inflated layout in that class but I can't figure out how to do it.

Here's the mycard class:

```
public class MyCard extends Card {


    public MyCard(String title) {
        super(title);
    }

    @Override
    public View getCardContent(Context context) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.mainactivity_contact_header, null);

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_first_letter)).setText(title);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_card_header);

        return view;
    }
}
```

What I would love to do is:

From my other class, be able to do something along the lines of "mycard.addViewToCard(RelativeLayout)"

is this even possible?

So I gave this a shot and I'm getting a null pointer exception.  Any ideas?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // the layout view for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_contacts_fragment,
            container, false);
    // inflate the view to add contact info (later to be added to 'view')
    View contactRow = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity().getBaseContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.mainactivity_contact_row, null);
    // The relative layout that houses the textview/imageview for contactRow
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) contactRow
            .findViewById(R.id.rl_main_fragment_root);
    // TextView for the contact name in contactRow
    TextView textView = (TextView) contactRow
            .findViewById(R.id.tv_contact_list_name);

    // Add the cards ui cardview
    CardUI mCardView = (CardUI) view.findViewById(R.id.cardsview);
    mCardView.setSwipeable(false);
    MyCard myCard = new MyCard("Contacts");
    // make a call to the linear layout in the cards UI layout so we can add
    // views later
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) myCard.getCardContent(
            getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.ll_card_header);

    char startingChar = '0';
    for (int i = 0; i < contactArray.size(); i++) {
        // Create new card for new letter
        String name = contactArray.get(i).mName;
        if (name.charAt(0) != startingChar) {
            startingChar = name.charAt(0);

            myCard = new MyCard(Character.toString(startingChar));
        }
        // this is the textView for the contact name in contactRow nested in
        // 'relativeLayout'
        textView.setText(name);
        //  add relativeLayout to the parent linearLayout from myCard
            //  the line below is Line 77
        linearLayout.addView(relativeLayout);
        // add myCard to the cardView
        mCardView.addCard(myCard);
        mCardView.refresh();
    }

    return view;
}
```

mainactivity_contact_header.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_card_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_first_letter"
            style="@style/CardTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="title" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@color/stroke" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the exception:

```
11-19 20:09:46.052: E/AndroidRuntime(790): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-19 20:09:46.052: E/AndroidRuntime(790): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-19 20:09:46.052: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3148)
11-19 20:09:46.052: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3131)
11-19 20:09:46.052: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.psesto.contactcards.main.MainListFragment.onCreateView(MainListFragment.java:77)
11-19 20:09:46.052: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
11-19 20:09:46.052: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
11-19 20:09:46.052: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
11-19 20:09:46.052: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
11-19 20:09:46.052: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
11-19 20:09:46.052: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
11-19 20:09:46.052: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-19 20:09:46.052: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-19 20:09:46.052: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-19 20:09:46.052: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-19 20:09:46.052: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 20:09:46.052: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-19 20:09:46.052: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-19 20:09:46.052: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-19 20:09:46.052: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks

Comment: What is on this line MainListFragment.java: line 77?

Comment: linearLayout.addView(relativeLayout);  Added a comment above the line in the op

Comment: so your linearLayout is null and causes NullPointerException. Check is your R.layout.mainactivity_contact_header xml really contains view with id = R.id.ll_card_header

Comment: It does.  I'm adding the xml code from that layout to the OP as well

Comment: Hmm, I've missed out that isn't only possible scenario - check your relativeLayout isn't null before executing linearLayout.addView(relativeLayout); Do you can use a debugger?

Comment: I think that may be it.  I'm about to head out though.  I'll comment again in about an hour.  Thanks for the help!  If that's it, I'll let you know so you can officially add it as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: @Vyacheslav  that did it.  Thank you so much.  add it as an answer so I can accept it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your `relativeLayout` is null, check it isn't null before executing

`linearLayout.addView(relativeLayout);`

or NullPointerException will be thrown like you can see in your LogCat output.